# Replacement motherboard, no audio in Windows 7 or Ubuntu - Hardware or software fault?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, audio, motherboard, bios

I recently got a Gigabyte GA-970A-DS3P motherboard. It appeared to be working fine, but blew a week or two ago. I got a replacement sent out (and changed my power supply, to be safe) that arrived this week, though it was denoted *B* stock. After installing it, I'm having major audio problems; the Realtek system reports everything is working fine but I'm hearing nothing from front or back panel. I have tried an installation of Ubuntu, which also says everything is fine and produces no sound. So far I've tried...

- Updating BIOS to latest firmware
- Updating drivers to latest on CD / website
- Uninstalling and re-installing RealTek
- Checking device manager (all fine, no errors)
- Confirming volume up / right outputs selected.
- Checked audio device enabled on BIOS

So far, nothing is working; with headphones plugged into frontpanel, I can detect a very faint hissing / crackling when a sound is playing, but no actual audio. If this is a bad audio chip on the mobo it would be bad luck, but not impossible. I'm just trying to determine what else to do to rule out software issue - any ideas how to procede? Obviously if the mobo is crap I'll send it back ASAP.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem to me.

Comment: are the connectors for the front audio jacks connected properly?

Comment: run a live cd of ubuntu, see if it can make sound work.

Comment: @Moab Tried with HD sound in front jack, AC-97 (and HD audio disabled on Bios) and even unconnected. I tried Ubuntu on a USB stick with no Joy; same problem, with some crackling if I listened carefully with headphones. Fair to assume Hardware fault ?

Comment: sound sounds like it to me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who helped; while it's relatively rare, the replacement motherboard had a defective audio chip. I sent it back and the new one worked instantly; quite time consuming to go through all the software testing but at least it's answered!